# How to compile C# / VB code with string interpolation using PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, powershell

I'm on **Windows** 10.0.18363.959 with **PowerShell** 5.1.18362.752

When trying to compile a **C#** or **VB.NET** code within **PowerShell** like this:

```
$Source = @'
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System

Public NotInheritable Class MainClass

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine($"{True}")
    End Sub

End Class
'@ 

$vbType = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source `
                   -CodeDomProvider (New-Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider) `
                   -PassThru `
                   -ReferencedAssemblies "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll", `
                                         "System.dll" `
                                         | where { $_.IsPublic }

[MainClass]::Main()

$Console = [System.Console]
$Console::WriteLine("Press any key to exit...")
$Console::ReadKey($true)
Exit(0)
```

I get a compiler error because the '**$**' character used for string interpolation:

> C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\oshdpbp1\oshdpbp1.0.vb(12) : >>>         Console.WriteLine($"{1}")

I'm aware that I could use **String.Format()** function instead, but I would like to know whether this issue can be solved without modifying the original VB.NET code (which of course it compiles right on **Visual Studio**).

Note that string interpolation was added in **VB14**. Maybe I'm missing how to specify the right VB compiler version, I don't have idea how to do so with PowerShell.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the line `Console.WriteLine($"{1}")` as such - what is the error message?

Comment: @Andrew Morton As I explained it is due the "$" char. The error message is: "Not a valid character". If I remove the "$" char then it compiles without errors.

Comment: Do you need to escape the $ from powershell's interpolation (ie with backtick `\`$"{True}"` ) or is it definitely coming from the vb compiler?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 is it definitely coming from the vb compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The `VBCodeProvider` has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_VisualBasic_VBCodeProvider__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__) with an `IDictionary` parameter which allows you to specify the compiler version.

This could work, but I can't test it right now:

```
$provOptions = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]]::new()
$provOptions['CompilerVersion'] = 'v14.0'

$vbType = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source `
                   -CodeDomProvider (New-Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider $provOptions) `
                   -PassThru `
                   -ReferencedAssemblies "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll", `
                                         "System.dll" `
                                         | where { $_.IsPublic }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. 14.0 is the required VB language version but not the (vbc.exe) compiler version, it does not work, it says the compiler executable can't be found. I found a value of "v4.0" is accepted but it does not compile (I get the syntax error of "$" char), and anyways that version number is strange because my latest vbc.exe version is 3.8.0.5. Maybe the version refers to .NET Framework targeting version, however I get the error mentioned at the start of this comment if I try to specify "v4.5", "v4.6", "v4.7.1" or "v4.8" and similar versions. I also tried ver. numbers of my msbuild.exe

Comment: Not sure how to implement the next in PowerShell script, but in theory I can specify the VB lang version in the VBC.exe command-line compiler options: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/langversion. This can be managed via the **CompilerOptions** property of the **System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters** class in .NET, however I get an error even specifying '-langversion:latest' and '-langversion:default', it says "latest" and "default" (and anything different than "10" or "11") are not a valid value for "langversion" option... I'm on VB16

Comment: @mklement0 Good point, I've fixed that. Alternatively a valid method syntax would be: `[SomeType]::new( arg1, ... )`